# Why Is There openssl_public_decrypt in PHP? Isn't the Public Key Supposed to Be For Encryption Only?

Tags: php, encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption, private-key

I apologize in advance for my ignorance.

I'm experimenting with public key cryptography trying to learn about RSA.

My understanding from every source I read is that there are two keys:

1. The public key. Anyone can use this to encrypt data, which can only be decrypted by the private key.
2. The private key. This can encrypt or decrypt data.

As I understand, the public key is public, so anyone could know it, while the private key is intended to be secret. As I understand it, one main reason for having a public and private key is so that data could be encrypted with the public key, and then stored or sent to the recipient through an insecure environment. We want to ensure an adversary who has the encrypted data/ciphertext and the public key can't feasibly get the original data.

It makes total sense to me that PHP would have openssl_public_encrypt, openssl_private_encrypt, and openssl_private_decrypt. openssl_private_encrypt, for example, "encrypts data with private private_key".

However, in PHP there is also a function "openssl_public_decrypt" which [specifically says](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-public-decrypt.php) it "decrypts data that was previous encrypted via openssl_private_encrypt()" and "Decrypts data with public key".

If there is a function capable of decrypting using the public key, and the public key is, well, public, then what is the point of encrypting that data at all?

Answer (score 1):

This is most commonly used in scenarios where the identity of the sender of a message or the integrity of the data being passed must be verified, more commonly referred to as a ***digital signature***.

Consider this hypothetical scenario: Alice wants to communicate with Bob, who needs assurance that Alice has authored the message and that the message hasn’t been tampered with in transit. Let’s assume Alice and Bob have already performed a public key exchange via Diffie-Hellman (or similar trusted mechanism).

1. Alice composes her clear text message to Bob (`msg`).
2. Alice then hashes `msg` using a collision-resistant digest algorithm

   ```
   digest = hash(msg)
   ```
3. Alice then encrypts `digest` using her private key `priv`, resulting in ciphertext `c`

   ```
   c = encrypt(digest, priv)
   ```
4. Alice then sends Bob both `msg` and `c` over any medium.
5. Bob, who already knows Alice’s corresponding public key (`pub`), decrypts the digest and compares the digest of the plaintext message contents he received to the decrypted hash

   ```
   hash(msg) === decrypt(c, pub)
   ```

If the comparison in step 5 succeeds, Bob can have reasonable assurance that the message has not been tampered with and that Alice (or someone with access to Alice’s private key) was the original author of the message.

Without the ability to decrypt using a public key, this type of verification wouldn’t be possible.